# Power line configuration

Tags: fuses, esd

For power, which configuration is best?

1. Fuse first, followed by an ESD diode
2. ESD diode first, and the fuse next

Comment: Realistically, neither appear to be generally suitable for what I regard as a power connection.

Answer (score 1):

The fuse should come first because the ESD diode might short out. If it does, the fuse will blow and prevent a fire.